# Upload photo from android

Tags: java, android, jersey

I want to upload the photo from android to server. I made the web service in Jersey Api. But I am getting 415 error when sending the photo.

Please help me to solve this.

I tried complete day..

Android Code:

```
FileBody bin = new FileBody(file, "image/jpg");
MultipartEntity mp = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
mp.addPart("file", bin);

httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
httppost.addHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
httppost.setEntity(mp);
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httppost);

if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream outstream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    response.getEntity().writeTo(outstream);
    return true;
}
```

Web service code:

```
@POST
@Path("uploadphoto")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
@Produces("text/plain")
public String uploadNotices(@FormDataParam("file") InputStream picStream) {
    try {
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("d://1.png"));
        int read = 0;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

        out = new FileOutputStream(new File("d://1.png"));
        while ((read = picStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
            out.write(bytes, 0, read);
        }
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "yes";
}
```

Comment: That response is from Server Side.Make sure you are sending the same thing which is server ask for. 500 is an internal server code

Comment: I am getting 415 ERROR Code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

415 is returned by the server when the entity sent in a request (content in a POST or PUT) has an unsupported mediatype.

Make sure you are sending the same media type which server is asking for.

Why 500 error occured ?? Read [this](http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E500.html)...

Comment: I set this on server @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA) and on android httppost.addHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data"); SO both are same. I think its right

Comment: but what about server?Has server any mechanism to accept this type of format? r u sure about this?

Comment: Getting 500 please can you tell me how to fix it